# std::ifstream.read() doesn't return anything to my buffer

Tags: c++, vector

When I am reading file with function `read()`, this function doesn't save data to my buffer `smoke`. I'm trying to read a file and save it to `smoke` with binary content.

How can I do it better, with vectors?

```
std::ifstream file("favicon.ico", std::ios::binary);
char ak47xd[1024];
std::string testxcs = "";
if (file.is_open()) {
    file.seekg(0, file.end);
    const size_t length = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);
    char smoke[318];
    file.read(smoke, length);
    printf("sss: %s\n",smoke);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("sk: %c\n",smoke[i]);
        testxcs += smoke[i];
        //printf("%i : %X\n", i, smoke[i] & 0xFF);
        //testxcs += (smoke[i] & 0xFF);
        //printf("Smoke: %s\n",testxcs.c_str());
    }
}
```

Output: 
[Here picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLoCg.png)

[Here problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24mWh.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the data you read really *is* a null-terminated string of printable characters? The ”.ico” suggests that it isn’t.

Comment: And how can i do this read  from ico ?

Comment: `(char *)&smoke` is **very suspicious**. I think you instead mean `smoke`

Comment: Congrats, you seem to have found a major bug in the C++ io library. Well at least if you use it correctly. Which you don't. What to you expect the content of an `.ico` file to be? And what will happen it it is longer that 318 byte? Anyway `smoke` is a char array so it *decays* to a pointer. `file.read((char *)&smoke, length);` should be `file.read(smoke, length);`. As soon as you need a cast in C++ you are likely to do it wrong...

Comment: @addicted_xC Print your array elements as integers instead of characters. (And remove the `%s` line completely.)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I did not think when I wrote it, you're absolutely right

Answer (score 2):

You are `reinterpret_cast`ing a `char**` to `char*`, your program's behaviour is undefined. *Probably* what is happening is the bytes are being written *somewhere else*.

You don't need three buffers to read into

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream file("favicon.ico", std::ios::binary);
if (file) {
    file.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() );
    std::streamsize length = file.gcount();
    file.clear();   // Since ignore will have set eof.
    file.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg );

    std::string testxcs(length, 0);

    file.read(testxcs.data(), length);

    std::cout << "sss: " << testxcs << "\n";
    for (char c : testxcs)
    {
        std::cout << "sk: " << c << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about the `char **` but your example should not work, `file >> testxcs [Error]`, in the std :: cout you need a `const char` and not a string, can you explain to me that it is supposed to do `file >> testxcs`? warns me of an error

Comment: You probably are lacking `#includes`, strings can be streamed. There may be bytes interpreted as whitespace, which `>>` will stop at. `tellg` does not return a count, it returns an opaque handle. `gcount` returns a size.